# how to show the full html source on fck editor?

Tags: fckeditor

fck editor does not show my html tags, when i view the source using fck editor the source does not include the html start and end tag, as well as the head tag, looks like it only shows the body tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly FCKediter format the file being edited and, it will remove tags, or replace tags, ex: `<head><body><style>` tags are replaced,

Select better version FCKEditor. You can find more other editors.

Mostly we use FCKEditor for editing contents inside this tags.